# AJAX / jQuery - Is it bad to fire jQuery before the AJAX call is succeeded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, latency, dom-manipulation

**Example**

Let's say I have a list of items. When I add a new item I use AJAX to send the data to the database. But obvious there is some latency between the AJAX call and the 'AJAX succes function'. (Which is a litte noticeable for the user)

A more userfriendly (well, faster) option would be to manipulate the dom (add item to the list) before the AJAX call is requested.

But this means the user view is already changed before the data is inserted in the database.

Can this method do in any way harm besides the fact that the dom is already manipulated before it knows of the call is 'succeeded' or 'failed'?

Kinds regards,

Dylan

Comment: What kind of "harm" are you talking about? It's showing the user something that doesn't necessarily match the saved data. If you're OK with that, then there's no harm.

Comment: This might be a better question for [ux.se].

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think it is a good approach. You could enhance it a bit. Maybe add a spinner or keep it faded (low opacity) until the call succeeds. If it succeeds then remove the spinner and get the dom element to show in full opacity.

Facebook uses a different approach when fetching posts. It shows a single placeholder and as soon as data is available, it renders on screen.

Comment: Yes, I also thought it was the best approach for me. The Facebook approach is also a good one. But what if the call is failed? Does Facebook remove the placeholder and display error messages?

Comment: If the call fails then show an appropriate message and remove the dom element.

Facebook only shows a graphical placeholder which stays in place even if network  has failed. I have not seen it doing anything else.